# Как сделать так, чтобы числа выводились в прямом порядке, тоже с использованием рекурсии?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, c++11, рекурсия, стек

При помощи этого кода числа выводятся в обратном порядке, что изменить в коде, чтобы они выводились в прямом порядке?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void foo() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    if (n == 0) {
        cout << "Числа в обратном прядке:";
        cout << "\n";
        return;
    }
    foo();
    cout << n << " ";
 }


 int main() {
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
     // Реализация по принципу стека, последний зашел - первый вышел, 
    //то есть задача которая помещена в стек самой последней выполняется 
    //   самой первой.
    cout << "Вводимые числа:" << endl;
    foo();
    cout << endl;
     system ("pause");
    }
```

Comment: Поставить вывод перед рекурсивным вызовом, а не после.

Comment: Не  получается так.

Comment: http://rextester.com/UAC72634

Comment: Хм, странно пробовала как сказали в VS ничего не получилось, спасибо огромное

Answer (score 1):

Например, добавить очередь - вот [так](https://ideone.com/XRp4qT): :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;


void foo(queue<int>*s = nullptr)
{
    if (s == nullptr) s = new queue<int>;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    if (n == 0) return;
    s->push(n);
    foo(s);
    cout << s->front() << " ";
    s->pop();
    if (s->empty()) delete s;
};


int main()
{
    foo();
    cout << endl;
}
```